# How to concatenate JSON data into string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have `{"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"}` JSON data.
I want to get a string `"Movie12013"` for that JSON. How to achieve that?

Comment: It's my mistake that I didn't elaborate the question properly. I am running a loop where I will get a json data in which keys are not constant, so can't do all below given correct results. BTW those methods I know perfectly. I want to do it without using any key, value extraction.

Comment: Rewrite your question then. Make sure you include what you've tried already.

Comment: i don't know why vote down the answers if the question it is not enough to understand or to see clearly.

Comment: even though this question look like silly, but i think this website created to help each other humbly. whatever the questions was, whomever the asker was it doesn't matter, everyone deserve best answer. +1 vote up for this questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haridharan/rWgn3/1/)
 try this,

```
   var json= {"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"};
  var append="";
  $.each(json,function(key,value){
  append+=value;
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understood correctly, you can do the following:

```
var json= {"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"};
var result="";
for( key in json){
  result+= json[key];
}
```

You don't have to know the number of properties or it's names before hand. This should work for simple scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to extract the JSON data using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

This assumes your JSON data is held in a variable named `json` which we've passed into the `parse()` method. This gives us the following JavaScript object:

```
{
    Title: "Movie1",
    Year: "2013"
}
```

We can now join the two values simply by concatenating them with the `+` symbol:

```
var result = data.Title + data.Year; // "Movie12013"
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
var jsonText = '{"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"}'
obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var string = obj.Title + obj.Year;
```

Comment: I am not down voting anyone.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming the JSON data is kept in a `jsonVarName` variable:

```
jsonVarName.title + jsonVarName.year
```