# how to concat two value in jsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

i have a request like that;

```
{
    "i0": "4299",
    "l2": "1788",
    "c1": "3",
    "l4": "0",
    "t35": "V001*",
    "i4":"0",
    "l3":"0",
    "csubeno":"4299"
}
```

and i have a json file;

`"ELJ": { "JTEXT1": { "value": "", "jsonPath": "$.parameters.request['c1']" }, "JNUM1": { "value": "", "jsonPath": "$.parameters.request['i0']"`

i need to concat that two value --> c1 and i0
i tried something like that but it doest work.

"jsonPath": "$.parameters.request[c1,i0]"

Any suggestions?

i need to concatenate two value (c1 and i0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate JSON data into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078340/how-to-concatenate-json-data-into-string)

Comment: ty for answer. $.c1,i0 --> I think it can be used as an array like this, but I want to use it as text side by side.

Comment: Why show 2 JSON files (a _request_, and a _json_ file ), and not tell what the relation between those two files is ?  What is the expected output?  (Or should we GUESS that your probably expect to get: `"34299"` ? (I do not like to GUESS .)

Comment: :) i expected <JTEXT1>3,4299</JTEXT1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a JSON file (`test.json`) like:

```
{ "testA": "valueA", "testB": "valueB" }
```

you can do:

```
cat test.json | jq '."testA" + ."testB"'
```

to get the [output](https://jqplay.org/s/3GfikXkbxsj): `"valueAvalueB"`

or you can do:

```
cat test.json | jq '"\(.testA)\(.testB)"'
```

to get the [output](https://jqplay.org/s/bFUoe5tAq8M): `"valueAvalueB"`

P.S. This was already answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45527623/724039

P.P.S:  `jq` is the tool that is available from GitHub here: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/

With your last edit, where output looks more like XML then JSON, you could do, (to get a JSON output!):

```bash
cat test.json | jq '{ "JTEXT1": (.testA + "," + .testB) }'
```

or

```bash
cat test.json | jq '{ "JTEXT1": "\(.testA),\(.testB)" }'
```

see: https://jqplay.org/s/ItQ06QjZDkW